# Do apple-touch-icons need to use the 'standard' filename convention or can I call them whatever I like?

Tags: html, ios

By 'standard' filename conventions, I mean:

- apple-touch-icon.png
- apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
- apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
- apple-touch-icon-144x144.png

I know that it is possible to omit the reference to these icons in the HTML and iOS will automatically search the root directory for files with these filenames.

But, assuming I am going to include a reference to these icons in the HTML, is it allowed to use different filenames for the icon image files?  For example:

- my-touch-icon-114x114.png
- 123456-114x114.png
- some-unique-id-114x114.png

So in my HTML it would look something like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/to/icons/some-unique-id.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="path/to/icons/some-unique-id-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="path/to/icons/some-unique-id-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="path/to/icons/some-unique-id-144x144.png">
```

The reason I ask is that I need to use different icons for different sections/pages of my site and I'd like to store all the icons in a single directory.  Obviously I can't store multiple versions of each icon all with the same filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you use `<link>` tags to link to your icon files correctly, then iOS should still be able to find them and you won't have to follow the standard naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help! I don't suppose you can point me towards a source for this information?

Comment: Find the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: @Pete H: Sure, here's the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4) for it. You can see it specifies its own file names when using `<link>` tags.